# Serializable class for

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I want to create a serializable `C#` class for the `XML` below.

```
<xml>
  <versions>
    <org.geotools.util.Version>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </org.geotools.util.Version>
    <org.geotools.util.Version>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </org.geotools.util.Version>
    <org.geotools.util.Version>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </org.geotools.util.Version>
  </versions>
  <gml>
    <entry>
      <version>V_20</version>
      <gml>
        <srsNameStyle>URN2</srsNameStyle>
        <overrideGMLAttributes>false</overrideGMLAttributes>
      </gml>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <version>V_10</version>
      <gml>
        <srsNameStyle>XML</srsNameStyle>
        <overrideGMLAttributes>true</overrideGMLAttributes>
      </gml>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <version>V_11</version>
      <gml>
        <srsNameStyle>URN</srsNameStyle>
        <overrideGMLAttributes>false</overrideGMLAttributes>
      </gml>
    </entry>
  </gml>
</xml>
```

I know I could do something like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "xml")]
interface IServiceSettings : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "versions")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "org.geotools.util.Version")]
    IList<string> Versions { get; set; }
}
```

But it is working only for `<org.geotools.util.Version>` elements that would contain strings only. How to expand this code over my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "xml")]
interface IServiceSettings<T> : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "versions")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "org.geotools.util.Version")]
    IList<T> Versions { get; set; }
}
```

Then the implementation of the interface will be generic as well

```
public class ServiceSettings<T> : IServiceSettings<T>
```

Comment: Good idea, but what if I had more such lists in my `IServiceSettings` interface and their types would be different?

Comment: Do they have a common subtype or no relation at all?

Comment: They are `strings`, always

Comment: can you give me an example? If they are the always `strings` you can just have a `string` property

Comment: Just try to serialize `versions` node without using generics.

Comment: Ok, I did it;) the problem wasn't in incorrect code for serialization... I was in here: `IList<T> Versions { get; set; }`... There was a missing word `public`... I made an abstract class with public property and everything is working fine now:P